# Import dataset into the ContextBroker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I currently have 2 large datasets (around 200GB) that I want to store into the `ContextBroker` in order to perform data-analysis on it. So far I've been able to setup a `ContextBroker` with a `MongoDB`. I also installed `Cygnus` with a `ONCHANGE` subscription in order to persist data from the `ContextBroker`. Is it possible to use `CKAN` to store my external dataset into the `FIWARE` platform or do I have to use something else?

**Edit1**: These datasets are a set of `json` files that contain objects with a series of events and are `timestamped`, `geo-located`.

**Edit2**: As requested a small sample of the data I'm referring to:

```
{"track":[  
{"time":"2015-11-16T00:45:29.016","midpoint":{"x":70.66,"y":188.90},"realworld":{"x":-7.49,"y":22.96},"RDCoordinate":{"x":161582.09,"y":383031.34},"UTM-WGS84":{"Latitude":51.4363489,"Longitude":5.4818640}},
{"time":"2015-11-16T00:45:29.022","midpoint":{"x":66.85,"y":189.61},"realworld":{"x":-7.53,"y":22.92},"RDCoordinate":{"x":161582.16,"y":383031.34},"UTM-WGS84":{"Latitude":51.4363489,"Longitude":5.4818649}},
{"time":"2015-11-16T00:45:29.029","midpoint":{"x":61.66,"y":189.92},"realworld":{"x":-7.60,"y":22.90},"RDCoordinate":{"x":161582.22,"y":383031.31},"UTM-WGS84":{"Latitude":51.4363486,"Longitude":5.4818658}},
{"time":"2015-11-16T00:45:29.082","midpoint":{"x":56.16,"y":190.47},"realworld":{"x":-7.66,"y":22.87},"RDCoordinate":{"x":161582.28,"y":383031.28},"UTM-WGS84":{"Latitude":51.4363483,"Longitude":5.4818667}},
{"time":"2015-11-16T00:45:29.090","midpoint":{"x":50.74,"y":191.64},"realworld":{"x":-7.71,"y":22.80},"RDCoordinate":{"x":161582.38,"y":383031.28},"UTM-WGS84":{"Latitude":51.4363483,"Longitude":5.4818681}},
{"time":"2015-11-16T00:45:29.112","midpoint":{"x":45.58,"y":192.07},"realworld":{"x":-7.78,"y":22.78},"RDCoordinate":{"x":161582.44,"y":383031.25},"UTM-WGS84":{"Latitude":51.4363480,"Longitude":5.4818690}},
{"time":"2015-11-16T00:45:29.151","midpoint":{"x":41.80,"y":193.42},"realworld":{"x":-7.80,"y":22.69},"RDCoordinate":{"x":161582.52,"y":383031.31},"UTM-WGS84":{"Latitude":51.4363486,"Longitude":5.4818701}},
{"time":"2015-11-16T00:45:29.197","midpoint":{"x":36.27,"y":194.43},"realworld":{"x":-7.86,"y":22.63},"RDCoordinate":{"x":161582.59,"y":383031.31},"UTM-WGS84":{"Latitude":51.4363486,"Longitude":5.4818712}}  
]}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question in order to elaboratate how your datasets looks like? I mean, they correspond to an "snapshoot" of context information, an historical sequence of events, etc. Thx!

Comment: (After looking to Edit1) Could you edit to add a sample or two of the JSON objects you refer to, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A posibility could be to model each item as an entity of type `Event` in the following way in Orion Conext Broker:

```
{
    "id": "Item1",
    "type": "Event",
    "time": {
        "value": "2015-11-16T00:45:29.016",
        "type": "DateTime"
    },
    "midpoint": {
        "value": {
            "x": 70.66,
            "y": 188.90
        },
        "type": "Object"
    },
    "realworld": {
        "value": {
            "x": -7.49,
            "y": 22.96
        },
        "type": "Object"
    },
    "RDCoordinate": {
        "value": {
            "x": 161582.09,
            "y": 383031.34
        },
        "type": "Object"
    },
    "UTM-WGS84": {
        "value": "51.4363489, 5.4818640",
        "type": "geo:point"
    }
}
```

(The above could be used as the payload for the `POST /v2/entities` operation to create that entity).

In this model, `time`, `midpoint`, `realworld`, `RDCoordinate` and `UTM-WG84` are entity attributes. Note the special attribute types for `time` and `UTM-WG84`:

- `time` uses `DateTime`, which is the NGSIv2 standard way to specify dates (see "Special Attribute Types" in the [NSGIv2 specification document](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/)). I'd suggest to include the timezone, in order to have a higher precissión (e.g. `2015-11-16T00:45:29.016Z`).
- `UTM-WG84` uses `geo:point`, which is the NGSIv2 standar way to specify point locations for entities (see "Geospatial properties of entities" in the [NSGIv2 specification document](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/)).

Comment: Hi fgalan. Thank you for your reply! This looks like it is indeed what I'm looking for, however this would require a lot of work to insert all the data. Is it possible to have this done automatically or not?

Comment: A script processing each row of data in your JSON file and sending the corresponding create entity command to Orion shouldn't be very difficult (even you could consider to "package" several entities in the same batch using `POST /v2/op/update` with APPEND actionType).